# Is »der Verlauf der Rettungsaktion« an appropriate collocation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, single-word-request, meaning-in-context

I read the following example from DWDS:

> der Minister informierte sich persönlich über den Verlauf der Rettungsarbeiten.

I am wondering whether ***Rettungsarbeiten*** can be replaced with ***Rettungsaktion*** in thus case?

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not be replaced.

According to the recent discussion about the differences in meaning, the phrase *über die Rettungsaktion* would imply that the minister only wanted to know briefly how the whole thing is going, but that he would not be interested in any details. No press statement would want to give an expression like this, thereby making the minister uninterested.

Furthermore, calling the whole th8ng *Rettungsaktion* implies that the whole thing is quite simple (like getting a cat down from a tree), and simple things don't need a minister to come and watch.

Comment: I followed the discussion about *Rettungsaktion* vs. *Rettungsarbeiten* yesterday, and I agreed on what was discussed there. However, in the context of today's question, I would oppose your opinion. For  me (former newspaper editor, not an expert in emergency medical services), in this context I find both words acceptable, including for a press release. -- Note on the minister's role: I think your argument can be turned against you: ministers usually do not care for the intricacies of rescue works at all; they want to get the general picture; especially a picture showing themselves.